# Firebase Messaging and Authentication Combined to Set Custom Token

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

PROBLEM: There are two Firebase services ([Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/) and [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth/)) we want to combine in our project. The goal is to set [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/) token a value we already know, not the one generated by `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`. Thus the same token is used to get authorized both on custom server and Firebase server. Moreover multiple application instances would have been reached with one token and would have accepted the same message.

RESEARCH:

- [Sending a Message to Multiple Registration Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json),
- [Creating Custom Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

QUESTION:

- Are these services supposed to be **combined**?
- Is `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` **equal** to what `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid)` generates?
- Is it **safe** to set an FCM token from client (message redirected to unsupposed device if hacked)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. The FCM service and Auth service are different and standalone -- one could be used without the other.
2. No. The token generated by the `getToken()` is the token that should be used to target the corresponding device for *push notifications*, `createCustomToken()` generates a token for *authentication*.
3. The FCM token is generated by calling the FirebaseInstanceId service on the client side -- it's the common usage, so yeah, I'd say it's *safe*.